# how to import and use variables defined in a class of another python program?

Tags: python, variables, import, python-import, python-class

I have this code try2.py. I want it to access its user input from another python script defined in a class.

```
from pytube import YouTube
from try3 import t


class down:

    def video(url,path):
        y = YouTube(url) 
        video1 = YouTube(url).streams.first().download(path)
        print(f"title:{YouTube(url).title}, views:{YouTube(url).views}, Length:{YouTube(url).length}")
        print("Successfully done")    
        return video1

t2 = down()
t2.video()
```

The program which has user input is try3.py.

```
from pytube import YouTube

class vdoterm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = url
        self.path = path
        
url = input("Enter the video URL: ")
path = input("Enter the path: ")

t = vdoterm(url,path)
```

I tried importing object "t", object "vdoterm" and access url but nothing worked.
How to access a variable defined in another program?

Comment: From your code `vdoterm` accepts `url` and `path`, however `__init__` of `vdoterm` does not show so..Also why cant you create an object of `down` class directly ?

Comment: Also how are you executing it? I dont see any communication of `try3.py` with `try2.py`, nowhere in `try3.py` are we calling anything of `try2.py`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way in case you want to follow the same files(which I think is not required when you can directly create an object of class `down`:
`try2.py`:

```
from pytube import YouTube

class down:

    def video(url,path):
        y = YouTube(url) 
        video1 = YouTube(url).streams.first().download(path)
        print(f"title:{YouTube(url).title}, views:{YouTube(url).views}, Length:{YouTube(url).length}")
        print("Successfully done")    
        return video1
```

`try3.py`:

```
from try2 import down
class vdoterm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = url
        self.path = path

    def video(self):
        t2_obj = down()
        t2_obj.video(self.url, self.path)
        
url = input("Enter the video URL: ")
path = input("Enter the path: ")

t = vdoterm(url,path)
t.video()
```

Comment: Pls Note: I havent executed the code, just provided you the direction to think on..